# The opposite of 'What do these two sentences have in common?'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

'What do these two sentences have in common?' The question is asking for similarity between the two sentences but if we had to say that we're looking for the difference. How would we say that?

Other than "What's the difference between the two sentences?"
Can it be something like 'What do these two sentences have in difference?'

Comment: Do you see some problem with "What's the difference between the two sentences?" (that seems to be a normal and natural expression)

Comment: "What do these two sentences have in difference" is not fluent English; we don't say "in difference" like we do "in common".  Your first suggestion of "What's the difference between the two sentences?" is probably the best, like James K says, although you could also say "How do the two sentences differ?"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> How do these two sentences differ?

Answer (score 0):

> What do these two sentences have in difference?

is definitely not something a native speaker would say.